# How to create a tmp dir in node without collisions

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, concurrency, directory

I have a need a create a temporary "scratch" directory on-demand in node.js.  The requirements are:

- the dirname should be randomized (i.e. `/tmp/aDIge4G/`
- the directory will be created within `/tmp` which may already have other randomly named directories.
- if the directory already exists, I should throw rather than use it and overwrite someone else's work
- this needs to be safe in a concurrent environment.  I can't just check if the directory exists and then create it if it doesn't because someone else may have created a directory with the same name *after* I checked.

In other words, I need the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528034/node-js-check-if-file-exists-before-creating-temp-file) question but for directories, not files.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793858/how-to-mkdir-only-if-a-dir-does-not-already-exist) answer says that what I want to do can be accomplished by `mkdir -p`, but Node doesn't have the `-p` flag for `fs.mkdir`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try [package "tmp"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tmp). It has a configuration parameter "template" which in turn uses Linux's [mkstemp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html) function which probably solves all your requirements.

Comment: Should I install another package in my repository which already has 16657 dependencies?... Where is it going?

Answer (score 73):

The current node api propose to create a temporary folder : https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdtemp_prefix_options_callback

which gives :

```
fs.mkdtemp(path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'foo-'), (err, folder) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(folder);
  // Prints: /tmp/foo-itXde2
});
// folder /tmp/foo-itXde2 has been created on the file system
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to create unique directories would be using [universally unique identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier) (UUIDs) within the path name.

Here is an example using [pure-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pure-uuid):

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');
const UUID = require('pure-uuid');

const id = new UUID(4).format();
const directory = path.join('.', 'temp', id);

fs.mkdirs(directory).then(() => {
  console.log(`Created directory: ${directory}`);
});
```

You will get an output like this:

> Created directory: temp\165df8b8-18cd-4151-84ca-d763e2301e14

**Note:** In the code above I am using [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) as a drop-in replacement for [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), so you don't have to care about `mkdir -p` because `fs-extra` will create the directory and any necessary subdirectories.

**Tip:** If you want to save your directories within the operation system's default temp directory, then you can make use of [os.tmpdir()](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_tmpdir). Here's an example of how this works:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const UUID = require('pure-uuid');

const id = new UUID(4).format();
const directory = path.join(os.tmpdir(), id);

fs.mkdirs(directory).then(() => {
  console.log(`Created directory: ${directory}`);
});
```

> Created directory: C:\Users\bennyn\AppData\Local\Temp\057a9978-4fd7-43d9-b5ea-db169f222dba

Comment: this is safer, faster, and better than node's mkdtemp!

Answer (score 0):

Use [fs.Stats](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) to check if it exists?

Something like this?

```
fs.stat(path, function(err, stats) {

    if (!stats.isDirectory()) {
        // create directory here
    }
}
```

Comment: What if someone else created a directory while I was doing `if (!stats.isDirectory())`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tmpDir` method of [fs-jetpack](https://github.com/szwacz/fs-jetpack) library. It uses just a `crypto.randomBytes` underneath and generates 128-bits-of-entropy random string as a directory name. If you create 2^32 (4 billions) temp-dirs, the statistical name collision chance is still 1 to 2^96, what is in the same realms of possibility as me being hit by a meteorite this second (somehow I live with this fear ;).

Relying on probabilities of big numbers (BTW, that's what git-hashes do) is much better and simpler than trying to figure out some clever way of omitting name collisions in concurrent environments.

Example code:

```js
const jetpack = require("fs-jetpack");

const tmp = jetpack.tmpDir();

// Do some stuff in the directory...
tmp.write("some_stuff.txt", "Hi!");

// After you're done with your directory easily remove it.
tmp.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
const {exec} = require('child_process')
const {promisify} = require('util')

promisify(exec)('mktemp -d')
  .then(({stdout: tempDirName}) => console.log(tempDirName))
```